# how to get rid of "null" when concating string in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have a class

```
class A{
    String name
    String address
}

def a = new A()
a.address = "some address"    
println "${a.name} ${a.address}"  => "null some address"
```

Here `a.name` is null, so the string printed will contains "null", however I hope the result is `"some address"` which ignore the null value.

I know I can use `println "${a.name ?: ''} ${a.address ?: ''}"` when printing, is there any simpler solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could redefine the `toString` method for Groovy's `null` object to return an empty string instead of `null`.

```
def a = [a:null, b:'foobar']
println "${a.a} ${a.b}"
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.metaClass.toString = {return ''}
println "${a.a} ${a.b}"
```

This will print:

```
null foobar
 foobar
```

If you only want to redefine `toString` temporarily, add the following after your last `print...` to change it back:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.metaClass.toString = {return 'null'}
```

---

You can also change `null`'s `toString` behavior using a Groovy `Category` [[1]](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy+Categories) [[2]](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/lang/Category.html). For example:

```
@Category(org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject) class MyNullObjectCategory {def toString() {''}}
use (MyNullObjectCategory) {
    println "${a.a} ${a.b}"
}
```

Comment: Building on your answer, you could also temporarily redefine it with a category: `@Category(NullObject) class NullObjectCategory { String toString() { '' } }`, and then `use` it wherever you want to squelch nulls: `use (NullObjectCategory) { assert "$a.a $a.b" == ' foobar' }`

Comment: thank you, this will solve my problem, I think no one want to get "null" when printing strings to users  on webpages

Comment: @JustinPiper Good point! Thanks for extra input. Updating answer.

Comment: @donnior Glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer that best resolved your question; see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) for more information. Accepting answers to your questions ensures the SO community will be more willing to help you in the future.

Comment: Just one question: have you guys thought of thread safety when coming up with this solution? Especially, the solution @JustinPiper came up with could be thread safe, i don't know if the use(Category) technique is bound to the current thread, but the initial solution I think is a little dangerous, if you only want to get rid of 'null' on the web page. Making the distinction between null and '' is important in a system log, for example.

Comment: Other threads won't see the changes made by `use`, but other functions called within the `use` would.

Answer (score 8):

You could implement a `toString` method in your class like so:

```
class A{
  String name
  String address
  String toString() {
    "${name ?: ''} ${address ?: ''}".trim()
  }
}
```

then do

```
def a = new A( address:'some address' )
println a
```

To get `some address` printed out, but this still used the Elvis operator as you had in your question...

Not sure there's much simpler you can do...

Comment: @donnior It's miles nicer than the same thing done in pure java...  The smallest I can think of for that is: `String.format( "%s %s", name == null ? "" : name, address == null ? "" : address ).trim()` ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if simpler, but:

```
[a.name, a.address].findAll().join(' ')
```

You may of course combine it with Tim's toString [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10517899/581845).

Notice that if any of the values might be "falsy" (e.g. 0), it will filter it out. You can fix that doing:

```
[a.name, a.address].findAll {it != null}.join(' ')
```

Comment: for a map [1:false,2:true,3:null].findAll{it.value != null}

Answer (score 0):

I think, a rather simple way of achieving it, i.e. removing null, is to concatenate the string and the use replace method.

```
myString=""
myString=myString + "Bla Bla"
myString.replace("null", '')
```